# How can I populate DataTables select menus dynamically?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, datatables

I've a DataTables table that displays information from a MySQL database. I'm trying to create drop-down filters, `<select>`, like the ones used [here](http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html). I know that the server-side tables can't use that precise example, but I'm not sure how to change it to make it work with a server-side database table.

How would I create drop-down menus, populated with information from the table/database, to filter a DataTables table?

EDIT: The server side is in PHP. I tried to query the database and create a separate menu with PHP and send the JSON-encoded information into select menus.

Comment: Ok, Before this question gets down-voted into the oblivion... Can you give us some code? Stuff you tried? It would be a lot easier to answer your *specific* question rather than give you millions of possibilities. Also is the server side in php, c#, ruby, python... etc... Give us something :)

Comment: Sorry! I edited it to add information. I don't really have any code to show, since I haven't found anything that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I don't know the specifics on how to achieve this with PHP ( I know it is most definitely possible) so I'll give you a generic rundown.You can ask me for specific details later and I'll edit my answer.

First you have to have the ajax source.

You can then use the same function ( from serverside ) to dynamically populate the options in your dropdowns. This is how

1st you make the html code for empty `<select id='id1'></select>`
Then you can use the `draw` event from datatables on which you can make an ajax request to populate the dropdowns `$(oTable).on("draw", function() { ... });`.
After that you can refresh the table and the dropdowns when one of the select option changes.

This is the most generic way of answering your (vague) question.

Here are some more resources:

Refresh ajax data: [how can I trigger jquery datatables fnServerData to update a table via AJAX when I click a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566463/how-can-i-trigger-jquery-datatables-fnserverdata-to-update-a-table-via-ajax-when/11566783#11566783)

Let me know if you have more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can figure out the rest of what I need from the general layout you gave.

Comment: I'm glad that I made it before it was downvoted to oblivion :)

Comment: Actually, I do have a question, sorry. I'm still not sure how to populate the dropdown menus. The source for all the table information is passed as a JSON object from the PHP code. My entire problem is that I don't know what the request to populate dropdown menus would be, not an issue with refreshing the table.

Comment: You can return the HTML code for the dropdown: `<option>1</option><option>2</option>` Just don't return a JSON object but just regular text (i'm not sure how to do that in PHP, but it has to be possible).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What I'm saying is that I'm trying to filter results from the table based on a user selection (from the select menu). The values that are in the table are the same values I want the user to be able to filter, e.g. in the column name, be able to select all results with 'Name' = 'Iro', or whatever. To do that, I want to have the values for the select boxes be the same as the values in the table, not 1, 2, etc., and have them created dynamically so that they always match the table records.

Comment: I understand. I gave 1, 2 as examples. You can create the HTML code on the serverside based on the data from the table. Then send the list of options through ajax. That way you can also send the list of currently selected filters so other filters also get updated so you won't end up with 0 results.